# How to find row and column index of maximum element in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, indexing

An example of what I want to achieve:

```
A =

     2     3     1
     1     8     4
     7     9     2
```

since the maximum element is 9, (i.e. the one in row 3, column 2)

```
[i, j] = maxindex(A);
```

I want `i` and `j` to be 3 and 2.

Is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)

Comment: Look at the [manual of `max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), especially its *second* output argument. I'd use `A` -> `A(:)` -> `max` -> `ind2sub` on second argument.